# How To Get A Class Instance From ArrayList?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and the code I'm working with is largely not my own, so please bear with me...

I have an arraylist containing several dozen instances of the same class, from which I'd like to extract the values of some variables in turn.

I've created an iterator and can iterate happily over the arraylist, the problem comes when I try to extract the class instances. Using .get(index) returns an Object and I'm ignorant of how to either convert an Object to the class type in order to access the variables or extract the instance in its own type.

Can anyone advise how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: sorry, I should have included the code in the first instance.

```
ArrayList TopicResults = results.getTopicResults(TopicNum);
ListIterator TopicResultsiter = TopicResults.listIterator();
while(TopicResultsiter.hasNext()){
                    int idx = TopicResultsiter.nextIndex();
                    ResultsList.Result result = TopicResults.get(idx);
                    String DocID = result.docID;
                    System.out.println(DocID);
                }
```

Comment: show your current code please .....

Comment: Your iterator should not be returning Object types if you are properly specifying a generic parameter.

Comment: Read up on **Casting** and **Generics**

Comment: And Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use casting :

```
MyClass classInstance = (MyClass)myArray.get(0);
```

Assuming that all instances in the list are of the type `MyClass` otherwise you might get `ClassCastException`

Using generics iteration should be easier and much safer :

```
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyClass>(); 
for (MyClass classInstance : myList) {
     classInstance.doSomething();
}
```

The type enclosed by the `<>` specifies the type of objects that are allowed to be stored in the list so this way already in compilation time you can safely use the list members without the need to check for their type. (Available from J2SE 1.5+)

Comment: (From 1.7: `List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();`.)

Comment: finally they got rid of this redudancy

Comment: Well some of it. If I want a new `List`, I think we know what implementation it's going to be. / From 1.5 you could use the shorter `List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList();`, though you will get a warning (which most people seem to completely ignore).

Comment: What about case when myArray init and have myArray.size()==0?

Answer (score 1):

`MyType object = (MyType) list.get(index);`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the object returned by the "get" Method of an ArrayList directly to an attribut of the same type as the ArrayList.

For example, if you have an

```
ArrayList<MyType> myList;
```

just use

```
MyType myObjectf = myList.get(0);
```

...should work without explicit typecasting

Comment: Right. The raw use of ArrayList remains for backward compatibility.